# How to update internal table without using MODIFY?

Tags: loops, abap, internal-tables

I have created internal tables where I want to update age of employee in one internal table by calculating it from another table, I have done arithmetic calculations to get age but now how can I update it by any alternate way instead of `MODIFY`?

```
WRITE : / 'FirstName','LastName', '  Age'.  
LOOP AT gt_items1 INTO gwa_items1.
  READ TABLE gt_header INTO gwa_header WITH KEY empid = gwa_items1-empid.
  gwa_items1-age = gv_date+0(4) - gwa_header-bdate+0(4).
        
  MODIFY gt_items1 from gwa_items1 TRANSPORTING age WHERE empid = gwa_items1-empid.
  WRITE : /  gwa_items1-fname , gwa_items1-lname , gwa_items1-age .
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: If it works, is there any reason why you want to write your code differently?

Comment: actually i have been practicing abap questions and based on their condtitions i am trying to solve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use field symbols (instead of work areas) by LOOPing over internal tables:

```
WRITE : / 'FirstName','LastName', '  Age'.  
LOOP AT gt_items1 
     ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_item1>).
  READ TABLE gt_header 
       ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_header>) 
       WITH KEY empid = <ls_item1>-empid.
  IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
    <ls_item1>-age = gv_date+0(4) - <ls_header>-bdate+0(4).
    WRITE : /  <ls_item1>-fname , <ls_item1>-lname , <ls_item1>-age .
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```

Field symbols have two advantages:

- They modify the internal table directly, no separate MODIFY is
  necessary.
- They are somewhat faster, than work areas.

Comment: It might be useful to explain the reason why `LOOP...ASSIGNING` is faster than  `LOOP...INTO`. It's because with `LOOP...INTO`, each loop iteration starts with copying the whole content of the table-line into the work-area, which takes a couple CPU cycles. A field symbol is a reference pointing directly at a line of the table, so the copying is no longer necessary. All that needs to happen each iteration is to reassign the field-symbol, which should usually be a very fast operation.

Answer (score 1):

Besides [József Szikszai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8829775/j%C3%B3zsef-szikszai)'s answer you could also use references:

```
write : / 'FirstName','LastName', '  Age'.

sort gt_header by empid. " <------------- Sort for binary search

loop at gt_items1 reference into data(r_item1).

  read table gt_header reference into data(r_header)
       with key empid = r_item1->empid binary search. " <------------- Faster read

  check sy-subrc eq 0. 

  r_item1->age = gv_date+0(4) - r_header->bdate+0(4).
  write : /  r_item1->fname , r_item1->lname , r_item1->age .
endloop.
```

I added some enhacements to your code also.

For more info check this [link](https://help.sap.com/SAPhelp_nw73/helpdata/en/14/11e7080c5c11d3b9350000e8353423/content.htm?no_cache=true#:%7E:text=Field%20symbols%20and%20data%20references%20allow%20you%20to,objects%20dynamically%20in%20ABAP%20programs.&text=When%20you%20address%20a%20field,are%20pointers%20to%20data%20objects.).